# Is it possible to solve $x + \log(x) = 6$ analytically?

Tags: calculus

$x + \log(x) = 6$

Can it be solved analytically? I asked around and no one knew how. Wolfram alpha shows only an approximation.

Comment: Lambert W function e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Maple gives $W(e^6)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x+\ln x =6$$
Exponentiate both sides,
$$xe^x=e^6$$
$$W_k(xe^x)=W_k(e^6)$$
$$\color{Red}{x=W_k(e^6)}$$

There are infinitely many branches of Lambert W function. $W_k$ denotes the $k$th branch. If you demand $x$ to be real, then $k=0$ is a choice (I don’t know if there are any other choices of $k$), which gives $x=W_0(e^6)$.

It is not easy to compute $W$ functions. If you want a ‘closed-form’ approximation of $W_0(e^6)$, there is an asymptotic expansion of $W_0$ for large argument:
$$W_0(x)=\ln x-\ln\ln x+\frac{\ln \ln x}{\ln x}+\cdots$$

Therefore, $$W_0(e^6)\approx 6-\frac{5\ln 6}6$$ and the error is around $0.01$.

Comment: Thanks! A numerical solution with approximation from Wolfram Alpha gives 5.27757, but $6 - \Frac{5 ln 6}{6}$ gives 4.501. Why the difference?

Comment: @Dweezahr I got $4.49666$ from Wolfram alpha. I won’t mind to post a screenshot if you want.

Comment: it used base 10 instead of base 2. Thanks. Where did you get the formula of W_0(x) from?

Comment: @Dweezahr I used base $e$... I got the formula from Wikipedia.

Comment: It is not easy to compute W functions, 
but only if all you have is abacus.
Otherwise there are plenty of tools that have this functions available.
See for example, 
[wiki]{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Software}.
It may be approximated numerically using Halley's method
with cubic convergence.
Also, you might add that since the argument 
of $\operatorname{W}$ in this case is positive, 
there is only one real solution.

Comment: @g.kov So you mean $k$ can only equal to $0$? Can you briefly prove it?

Comment: @Szeto: The bright side is, that we don't need to prove 
this every time, since 
the behavior of the real branches 
$\operatorname{W_0}$
$\operatorname{W_{-1}}$
is well-known for a long time already.
For $x\ge0$ only one real solution
$\operatorname{W_0}(x)$,
for $x<-1/e$ no real solutions,
for $-1/e<x<0$
two real solutions
$\operatorname{W_0}(x),\operatorname{W_{-1}}(x)$,
and for $x=-1/e$
also just one real value,
$\operatorname{W_0}(-1/e)=\operatorname{W_{-1}}(-1/e)=-1$.